# Provable logged session site snapshot? Is it possible to do in a trustless way?

Tags: cryptography, trust

Information you get from the internet is increasingly tailored specifically for "you".
Google search results or youtube comments ranking algorithms have way to much power not to be fully disclosed.
You can make a snapshot of a web site using a web archiving service and that service could testify its authenticity.
How could one have a similar "provable" snapshot for you specific user session?
Of course, if you give your access tokens to the archiving service they could testify it but how could that be done in a trustless way?

I thought about using a browser extension but nothing prevents someone from using a tempered browser build?

Could a proxy record of the encrypted communications be used somehow?
Would a provable link between it and the decrypted version of the interaction be possible without exposing the user private key?

Are there any methods already available?
If not...any ideas?

Thanks

edit:

TC "kind of" solves the "secured against its owner" that I'm assuming browser extension also solve but I don't think TC would help since you can just build your own version of the browser.
If that would be possible and a "man-in-the-middle attack" could be prevented then a simple "webRTC tab sharing" record would do it (or some other king of record and replay method)

I was thinking in more in some kind of method where you would log into the site and "only" after that all communications would go through a proxy.
You would record you interaction with the site and close the connection.
Then you would give the TLS key and all the saved interaction to the proxy and it would be able to replay that interaction with the cached network traffic.
Is something like that possible?

Comment: given that javascript can arbitrarily modify a page at basically any time (e.g. recognising an "incognito" session) it would probably need to be a pretty invasive snapshot of the DOM that stripped out (or sanitised) any code.  sounds a bit like you want "trusted computing" which is generally disliked for widely documented reasons

Comment: Hi Sam. I edited the post to try and be a little more specific. Tell me what you think

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding how TC works (AFAIK it also doesn't exist in a form that would be useful here).  recording network traffic is certainly possible (but probably awkward with websockets, etc).  but nothing would stop the javascript from doing something different in the replayed version.  why not just sign the recording of a screencast or a printed version of the page?

Comment: The idea is to prevent the client from tampering with the snapshot although placing trust on the proxy. If one could implements some way to have multiple proxy servers at the same time then by applying some consensus mechanism it would be pretty trustless?

Comment: Currently you can use an archiving service like https://archive.org/ as legitimate evidence but it doesn't work for user logged sessions.
Would TLS still work if client suddenly changes IP?
If so it would be possible to proxy the connection only after user entered his password so that when he discloses if TLS symmetric key to the proxy he wouldn't be able to decrypt it.

Comment: I guess server allow multiple IP for the same session to cope with load balanced proxies. Also you might as well guessed that I'm not really an expert in the issue :)

Comment: I'll prefix this by saying I'm struggling to understand your comments.  I might be misinterpreting you, but I don't think so. 1) I think you're misunderstanding what TLS is used for and protects.  2) Servers generally don't notice/care about client IP address (e.g. what should happen if you're on a mobile device that switches from wifi to mobile data).  3) I'd suggest checking out https://github.com/webrecorder/pywb if you haven't already

Comment: I'm trying to find if it's possible to have something like web.archive.org that works for user sessions. It can't be a client side "snapshot" because then the client couldn't prove it's authenticity

Comment: The problem is to have the proxy as a witness without exposing private info to it. I know the proxy can't decript communications but the whole idea is to give it the TSL key after the session is over.

Comment: I'm assuming no sensitive data would be transferred after login of course

Comment: Found this https://webrecorder.io
It's allows logged session captures but don't think they're provable

Comment: but the client/user should be involved! otherwise how would the user know the archive got the "same" page?  I'm not sure why you keep focusing on TLS keys as well, they're ephemeral by design.  just thought, what do you mean when you say "user sessions"?  if you give this proxy the ability to see all traffic that passes through a TLS connection then you'll have broken the security of lots of sites, e.g. `Authorization: Bearer` or similar cookies

Comment: The proxy would only be able to see the traffic "after" the TLS session is over and the client send it the expired key.
Also the proxy would only be involved after the user login form so the traffic would not contain any secrets

Comment: As long as the user doesn't access a page containing secret information of course

Comment: if the user goes to a sensitive page by mistake then he would simply not send the session key to the proxy. The main problem would be if the site inadvertently exposes sensitive information in metadata and the user is not aware

Comment: the TLS session key isn't the issue, I'd suggest reading through the OAuth2 protocol!  I'd also suggest looking through at the network activity in the dev-tools of your favourite browser.  lots of sensitive stuff is constantly being passed around with lifetimes significantly longer than a bored user who presumably wants to hit "archive" as soon as possible and not worry about the consequences

Comment: I don't get the "longer lifetimes"? The idea is to proxy only during the snapshot

Comment: yup, but you've implicitly given the proxy server permission to perform subsequent http requests to the target server for a while.  this is because it's implicitly been given all security tokens needed in the network traffic shared with it.  it can perform these requests until the tokens timeout, which might be minutes for oauth2 tokens or months in other commonly used schemes

Comment: Haaa..ok. I didn't get into details but yes, I'm assuming you only disclose the key "after" it expires. The proxy server only needs it to decrypt cached responses as a way to validate the snapshot

Comment: the difficult part would be to check if there's no sensitive data in those cached responses

Comment: again, please read through some real code/protocols that do this.  almost every request to a site contains sensitive headers.  also there's a lot more keys involved here than just those involved in TLS (where there are at least two, the symmetric one that actually encrypts data and an asymmetric one to negotiate the symmetric key).  once you can decrypt the TLS data then you'd almost certainly get the user's session keys that authenticate them to the site, and hence the ability to perform another HTTP request

Comment: If I knew all the details of the protocol I wouldn't be asking.
I wish you also read my comments more carefully because as I said several times only "after" the user login would the communications be proxied and no page exposing private data should be visited.
Then the TLS session should be ended to enforce key expiration before sending it to the proxy.
And by the way, this key can be sent only when the server needs to "testify" the snapshot authenticity.

Comment: also...since TLS has forward secrecy it's unlikely that it leaks sensitive data by decrypting that particular data.

Comment: I am trying to read your comments carefully!  again, please read some protocols or look at how some are used in your browser.  TLS forward secrecy isn't protecting what you seem to think it is.  A browser makes many TLS connections to a server when you open a single page, each can/will use different crypto keys.  these are separate/independent from how the user is identified/authenticated.

Comment: ok, maybe I didn't explain myself very well. By proxy I mean a "web proxy" or a "proxy site". It would only be involved in the process during the interaction the client wants to "provably" register